# Sum of columns from two GROUP BY Sub-Queries of the same underlying table

Tags: mysql, sql

*UPDATE*
I determined a significantly more concise and computationally optimal way of expressing this statement. No subqueries no multiple joins.:

```
SELECT
month(hire_date) as month, 
sum(case when gender ="m" then 1 end) as male,
sum(case when gender ="f" then 1 end) as female,
count(*) as total 
FROM employees
GROUP BY MONTH(hire_date)
```

---

Using the MySQL [Employees Sample Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/), I am querying the same employees table twice via subquery and cross joining the results to get the pivot table below. I am looking to create a final column that would be the sum of `mcount` and `fcount`

```
Month,Gender,mcount,gender,fcount
'1','M','14310','F','9549'
'2','M','14659','F','9789'
'3','M','16200','F','10717'
'4','M','15363','F','10190'
'5','M','15545','F','10398'
'6','M','15000','F','10003'
'7','M','15260','F','10345'
'8','M','15250','F','10146'
'9','M','14632','F','9684'
```

I have tried to use subqueries again to create this column, but it's making it evident that my two GROUP BY sub-queries are the wrong way to go about building this pivot table.

```
SELECT mbm.month, mbm.gender, mbm.count as mcount, fbm.gender, fbm.count as fcount
FROM
(SELECT MONTH(hire_date) as Month, gender, COUNT(*) as count
FROM employees
WHERE gender = "M"
GROUP BY gender,MONTH(hire_date)
) as mbm

CROSS JOIN (SELECT MONTH(hire_date) as Month, gender, COUNT(*) as count
FROM employees
WHERE gender = "F"
GROUP BY gender,MONTH(hire_date)
) AS fbm on mbm.Month = fbm.Month
```

Comment: If male and female are the only values in the gender column, then the sum of the two pivoted column is basically the record count for the given month.

Comment: cross joins don't have an ON clause, this should be written as a full outer join, in case there are months where no males or no females exist. As shadow alludes to, selecting the gender in a query that has only one gender in the where clause, is pointless. `select coalesce(mbm.month, fbm.month) as month, mbm.count as malecount, fbm.count as female count from ... full outer join ... on mbm.month = fbm.month`

Comment: The new column I'm trying to get is indeed the sum for the given month, but what are you suggesting?

Comment: Replace the ... with the subqueries. Subqueries simply need to SELECT month(), count() ... where gender = whatever). Remove to group by / select the year if needed

Comment: Ps, your query says COUNT but you just said SUM. Decide which it is?

Comment: I do want the count of all the occurrences of male then female, and the last column is the SUM of those two occurrences showing a total.

Comment: Ignoring emulating a full outer join in MySQL for now, I've cleaned up the code per your advice, but how would I create the new final column? ```SELECT COALESCE(mbm.month, fbm.month) as month, mbm.count as malecount, fbm.count as femalecount from

(SELECT MONTH(hire_date) as Month,  COUNT(*) as count
FROM employees
WHERE gender = "M"
GROUP BY gender,MONTH(hire_date)
) as mbm

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT MONTH(hire_date) as Month, COUNT(*) as count
FROM employees
WHERE gender = "F"
GROUP BY gender,MONTH(hire_date)
) AS fbm 

on mbm.Month = fbm.Month```

Comment: doesn't seem elegant or efficient but I just added a third subquery left join of ``` LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT MONTH(hire_date) as Month, COUNT(*) as count
FROM employees
GROUP BY MONTH(hire_date)
) AS allbm```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A significantly more concise and computationally optimal way of expressing this statement. No subqueries,no multiple joins, and easy to read:

```
SELECT
month(hire_date) as month, 
sum(case when gender ="m" then 1 end) as male,
sum(case when gender ="f" then 1 end) as female,
count(*) as total 
FROM employees
GROUP BY MONTH(hire_date)
```